# Angular 9 HMR : how to disable auto scroll to top (page rerenders with hmr) when code is changed?

Tags: angular, package.json, angular9

[image]I am using Angular hot module replacement for development. Whenever I change in my code the HMR rerenders the code in browser **but it also scrolls the page to TOP.** I don't want that.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.0",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "^2.1.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.6.0"
  }
```